I'M trying to scrape the website payscale.com to get some data there using BeautifulSoup, but i can't manage to get it no matter what i did
Here are my codes:
`import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.payscale.com/college-salary-report/majors-that-pay-you-back/bachelors/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup_job = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup_job, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all('table', class_="data-table")
print(table)`

`Even when I do this, it is still not working. Is there anyone who can help me, please?'
page=1
while page <= 34:
 
    response = requests.get(
        f"https://www.payscale.com/college-salary-report/majors-that-pay-you-back/bachelors/page/{page}")
    page += 1

I have used selenium to get that done, but it is still not working.
I'm trying to see if someone can review and provide some hint on how to get that done.
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.payscale.com/college-salary-report/majors-that-pay-you-back/bachelors"
response = requests.get(url)
soup_job = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup_job, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all('table', class_="data-table")
print(table)

When I print the table, I expected to get some text or data, but it gives me an empty list.
I have changed the class name to see if I can get something better; it is showing me the same issue, and when I tried to use find instead of find all, it returned none instead of an empty list.
I want to get the data inside the table there, and after that, I will be able to tract the head and the body of the table to get the data I want; nothing works for me so far.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

You're using requests, which cannot process javascript content.

Do you have any idea about what to use instead of requests?

@Dave: If you’ve determined that the content being scraped needs to process JavaScript or in some way perform functionality that a browser would perform then plain HTTP requests alone wouldn’t do that.  You’d need to use a “headless browser” tool like Selenium to process the page’s client-side functionality in memory so you can observe the resulting updated DOM. Is that what you are observing?  The question is currently light on such details.

I have tried this but still no answer; from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

Set up Selenium
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run without a GUI
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
Load the website
url = "https://www.payscale.com/college-salary-report/majors-that-pay-you-back/bachelors"
driver.get(url)
Extract data
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "data-table")
for element in elements:
print(element.text)

@Dave: Relevant code belongs in the question, not in comments.  And “still no answer” tells us nothing about the problem.  This is a good time for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  With a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes and observe the exact runtime values and behaviors.  When you do this, what specific operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

I suspect that you are being blocked by the site. You need to be a little stealthy.
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://www.payscale.com/college-salary-report/majors-that-pay-you-back/bachelors/"

driver = uc.Chrome(headless=False, use_subprocess=True)

driver.get(URL)

# Wait for page to fully load. Could actually wait for a specific element.
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

data = []

for row in soup.select_one("table.data-table > tbody").select("tr"):
    data.append({
        "rank": row.select_one("td.csr-col--rank .data-table__value").text,
        "school": row.select_one("td.csr-col--school-name .data-table__value").text,
        "degree": row.select_one("td.csr-col--school-type .data-table__value").text,
        "early": row.select_one("td:nth-of-type(4) .data-table__value").text,
        "mid": row.select_one("td:nth-of-type(5) .data-table__value").text,
    })

driver.quit()

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data)

This is what the output should look like:
   rank                                            school     degree     early       mid
0     1                             Petroleum Engineering  Bachelors   $98,100  $212,100
1     2      Operations Research & Industrial Engineering  Bachelors  $101,200  $202,600
2     3  Electrical Engineering & Computer Science (EECS)  Bachelors  $128,500  $192,300
3     4                                Interaction Design  Bachelors   $77,400  $178,800
4     5                                  Building Science  Bachelors   $71,100  $172,400
5     6                  Applied Economics and Management  Bachelors   $81,200  $169,300
6     7                             Actuarial Mathematics  Bachelors   $71,200  $167,500
7     8                     Optical Science & Engineering  Bachelors   $81,500  $166,400
8     9                            Quantitative Economics  Bachelors   $78,400  $165,100
9    10                               Operations Research  Bachelors   $94,900  $164,900
10   11                               Systems Engineering  Bachelors   $89,700  $163,800
11   12                    Information & Computer Science  Bachelors   $73,200  $162,900
12   13                                 Public Accounting  Bachelors   $71,500  $162,200
13   14                                 Cognitive Science  Bachelors   $80,300  $162,100
14   15                        Aeronautics & Astronautics  Bachelors   $89,800  $161,600
15   16                                 Aerospace Studies  Bachelors   $64,500  $158,400
16   17                                          Pharmacy  Bachelors   $71,500  $158,000
17   18                              Managerial Economics  Bachelors   $78,200  $157,800
18   19                                   Foreign Affairs  Bachelors   $65,200  $157,700
19   20                                 Political Economy  Bachelors   $75,800  $156,700
20   21                              Chemical Engineering  Bachelors   $87,700  $156,100
21   21                  Marine Transportation Management  Bachelors   $78,500  $156,100
22   23               Computer Science (CS) & Engineering  Bachelors   $93,500  $154,100
23   24                    Corporate Accounting & Finance  Bachelors   $79,100  $154,000
24   25                         Computer Engineering (CE)  Bachelors   $92,000  $153,800


Super! Thank you. It works fine!

BeautifulSoup is just a parser as it retrieves the static HTML content from the server and can't handle JavaScript-rendered content, while Selenium can because it emulates a browser.

Even when I used Selenium, I still couldn't get the result.

Do you have any idea about what to use instead of BeautifulSoup and Selenium to get that done?

It looks like you're running into a problem where the table data isn't being retrieved as expected from the page. The issue might be related to how the content on the page is loaded and rendered. Many modern websites use JavaScript to load content dynamically, which means that the data you're trying to scrape might not be present in the initial HTML response but rather rendered after JavaScript is executed in the browser. Here's a breakdown of what's happening and how to proceed.
Why it's not working

JavaScript rendering

The requests and BeautifulSoup libraries can only retrieve and parse the static HTML of a webpage. If the content (like the table data you're trying to scrape) is loaded dynamically via JavaScript, these tools won't be able to capture it.
Dynamic content loading: The table data you're trying to scrape could be loaded dynamically after the initial page load. This is common for pages that display data from APIs or use JavaScript to populate tables.
You mentioned that you've tried using Selenium, which is a good approach because Selenium can handle JavaScript rendering and capture the fully rendered HTML. Below is an example of how you can modify your Selenium script to scrape the table data.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import by 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

# Set up Selenium WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url = "https://www.payscale.com/college-salary-report/majors-that-pay-you-back/   bachelors"
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the page to load completely
time.sleep(5)  # Adjust this time if necessary for the page to fully load

# Find the table(s)
tables = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "data-table")

# Iterate through the tables and print their content
for table in tables:
rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:
    columns = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    column_data = [col.text for col in columns]
    print(column_data)

    # Close the driver after scraping
    driver.quit()

Why Selenium works:

Selenium interacts with the page just like a browser, so it will wait for the JavaScript to load and then grab the fully rendered HTML.The code uses find_elements to find the tables and then iterates over them to extract the data.


The most AI-looking response
